# How does fix this Warning: DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE

Tags: reactjs, middleware

How does fix this Warning: DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE
in simple Create React App and when I don't use Webpack

[image]

Comment: hi, were you able to fix this issue??

Comment: @wasicool2 Hi, no.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by updating webpackDevServer.config.js file.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserversetupmiddlewares

remove

```
onBeforeSetupMiddleware(devServer) {
  // Keep `evalSourceMapMiddleware`
  // middlewares before `redirectServedPath` otherwise will not have any effect
  // This lets us fetch source contents from webpack for the error overlay
  devServer.app.use(evalSourceMapMiddleware(devServer));

  if (fs.existsSync(paths.proxySetup)) {
    // This registers user provided middleware for proxy reasons
    require(paths.proxySetup)(devServer.app);
  }
},
onAfterSetupMiddleware(devServer) {
  // Redirect to `PUBLIC_URL` or `homepage` from `package.json` if url not match
  devServer.app.use(redirectServedPath(paths.publicUrlOrPath));

  // This service worker file is effectively a 'no-op' that will reset any
  // previous service worker registered for the same host:port combination.
  // We do this in development to avoid hitting the production cache if
  // it used the same host and port.
  // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2272#issuecomment-302832432
  devServer.app.use(noopServiceWorkerMiddleware(paths.publicUrlOrPath));
}
```

> add

```
setupMiddlewares: (middlewares, devServer) => {
  if (!devServer) {
    throw new Error('webpack-dev-server is not defined');
  }

  devServer.app.get('/setup-middleware/some/path', (_, response) => {
    response.send('setup-middlewares option GET');
  });

  // Use the `unshift` method if you want to run a middleware before all other middlewares
  // or when you are migrating from the `onBeforeSetupMiddleware` option
  middlewares.unshift({
    name: 'first-in-array',
    // `path` is optional
    path: '/foo/path',
    middleware: (req, res) => {
      res.send('Foo!');
    },
  });

  // Use the `push` method if you want to run a middleware after all other middlewares
  // or when you are migrating from the `onAfterSetupMiddleware` option
  middlewares.push({
    name: 'hello-world-test-one',
    // `path` is optional
    path: '/foo/bar',
    middleware: (req, res) => {
      res.send('Foo Bar!');
    },
  });

  middlewares.push((req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!');
  });

  return middlewares;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

simple solution is here
In file: node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js

**change this code**

```
onBeforeSetupMiddleware(devServer) { // Keep evalSourceMapMiddleware// middlewares beforeredirectServedPath` otherwise will not have any effect
// This lets us fetch source contents from webpack for the error overlay
devServer.app.use(evalSourceMapMiddleware(devServer));

if (fs.existsSync(paths.proxySetup)) {
// This registers user provided middleware for proxy reasons
require(paths.proxySetup)(devServer.app);
}
},
onAfterSetupMiddleware(devServer) {
// Redirect to PUBLIC_URL or homepage from package.json if url not match
devServer.app.use(redirectServedPath(paths.publicUrlOrPath));

// This service worker file is effectively a 'no-op' that will reset any
// previous service worker registered for the same host:port combination.
// We do this in development to avoid hitting the production cache if
// it used the same host and port.
// https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2272#issuecomment-302832432
devServer.app.use(noopServiceWorkerMiddleware(paths.publicUrlOrPath));
}
```

**from**

```
  setupMiddlewares: (middlewares, devServer) => {
if (!devServer) {
throw new Error('webpack-dev-server is not defined')
}

if (fs.existsSync(paths.proxySetup)) {
    require(paths.proxySetup)(devServer.app)
}

middlewares.push(
    evalSourceMapMiddleware(devServer),
    redirectServedPath(paths.publicUrlOrPath),
    noopServiceWorkerMiddleware(paths.publicUrlOrPath)
)

return middlewares;
}
```

Comment: This is a valid solution but only for an ejected CRA app

Answer (score -4):

This problem is in WebStorm only. If you start in Visual Studio Code you can see this warning near one second and then everything is ok.

[image]